# Dokku with Puppeteer Chrome headless : "Failed to launch chrome"

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, dokku

**Dokku** is an alternative for **Heroku**, with a self hosted version.

I try to use Puppeteer Chrome headless with this code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: true,
     args: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
     ]
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
```

When **Dokku** build and launch the app, I get this error:

> Error: Failed to launch chrome!
>   /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-641577/chrome-linux/chrome:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory TROUBLESHOOTING:
>   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

The troubleshooting page say to install packages.
But **Dokku** haven't access to this installed package because he working with Docker.

Also, I've installed buildpack with this command:

```
dokku buildpacks:add <app_name> jontewks/puppeteer
```

or this git repository

```
dokku buildpacks:add <app_name> https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack.git
```

I execute the deploy command again `dokku deploy <app_name>` and I've always errors in logs.

Comment: Any update on this one ? how you fixed this ? @primax

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this if anyone run into the same problem (like I did). A solution has been proposed in a [github project](https://github.com/mskog/dokku-puppeteer-example) by **mskog**.

The root cause for the inability of `puppeteer` to launch is because some libraries are missing in the container. So, you need to install them when creating it. For that, **mskog** propose to use [`dokku-apt`](https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt), a plugin for Dokku that will install the libraries for you when the container is started.

After installing `dokku-apt`, create a file named `apt-packages` at the root of your project and add the list of required libraries in it.

> **Since version 3.0, puppeteer requires a new library `libgbm-dev` that is not specified in the github project, use the following list below.**

```
gconf-service
libasound2
libatk1.0-0
libc6
libcairo2
libcups2
libdbus-1-3
libexpat1
libfontconfig1
libgcc1
libgconf-2-4
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
libglib2.0-0
libgtk-3-0
libnspr4
libpango-1.0-0
libpangocairo-1.0-0
libstdc++6
libx11-6
libx11-xcb1
libxcb1
libxcomposite1
libxcursor1
libxdamage1
libxext6
libxfixes3
libxi6
libxrandr2
libxrender1
libxss1
libxtst6
ca-certificates
fonts-liberation
libappindicator1
libnss3
lsb-release
libgbm-dev
xdg-utils
wget
```

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling with this problem